# Mercurial Extension with no/default options

Tags: python, mercurial-extension

Say I want an extension that I can execute as follows:  `hg sayhi`

I tried the following, but it tells me there are invalid arguments:

```
def sayhi(ui, repo, node, **opts):    
  """Says Hello"""
  ui.write("hi")

cmdtable = {                     
    "sayhi":  (sayhi, [], '')
}
```

It seems no matter what I do, I need to give it an option like `hg sayhi s`. 
Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, got a fix. I removed the node parameter from the method signature and it works.